# C++ Error, adding even numbers

Tags: c++, math, fibonacci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of even fibonacci numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574611/sum-of-even-fibonacci-numbers)

At the moment, I am doing some Project Euler problems and I am up to the second problem.

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I am doing the problem in C++, and I think my code is perfectly fine, because up to a point, everything is correct, but then, everything spirals out of control...
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int evsum = 0;
    while (a < 4000000 and b < 4000000) {
        a = a + b;
        b = a + b;
        if (a % 2 == 0)
            evsum += evsum + a;
        if (b % 2 == 0)
            evsum = evsum + b;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
        cout << evsum << "evensum" << endl;
    }
}
```

The xCode compiler prints everything out correctly until...

```
2
3
2evensum

5
8
10evensum

13
21
10evensum

...

...

233
377
198evensum

610
987
1006evensum
```

For some reason, the compiler adds 610 to 198 and thinks it is equal to 1006!!! How do I fix this???

Comment: Take a deep breath and repeat: "The compiler is not wrong, the compiler knows how to add, the compiler is not wrong..."

Comment: the point of this problem, i think, is to notice that there's a pattern in which fibonacci numbers are even... you can save yourself an awful lot of % 2s if you think about it.

Comment: Hopefully the first lesson you'll learn trying to solve these questions is `brute force is not enough`, and the second lesson is `maths is beautiful`. The third lesson is, `my brain can make the difference`.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2574611/1155650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addition is completely bogus. The reason this bug shows itself so late in the series is that `a` is never even until then (except `2` in the beginning), only `b`. Fix that and just use `evsum += a` and `evsum += b`.

[Here's a live example on Ideone of the fixed code.](http://ideone.com/RFas1)

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
evsum += evsum + a;
```

Is equivalent to

```
evsum = evsum + evsum + a;
```

Notice that this adds in `evsum` twice.  This matches your bug; the computer added 610 and 198 to get 1006 because 610 + 198 + 198 = 1006, since the 198 is added in twice.  I think you meant for this to be

```
evsum += a;
```

Try changing this and see if it fixes things.

That said, let's see if we can spot a pattern in the even Fibonacci numbers.  The Fibonacci sequence looks like this:

```
 0  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55 89 ...
 ^        ^        ^        ^
```

Notice that the pattern is even, odd, odd, even, odd, odd, even, odd, odd, etc.  This trend continues, and if you'd like you can even prove that this is true by induction.  Given this, you could make your code a bit cleaner by just summing up every third Fibonacci number (starting at zero).  You could probably optimize this even further by finding a nice closed-form expression for the sum of these numbers, but I'll leave that as an exercise. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I work a lot in Python and in Python everything is += so i got mixed up, thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

```
evsum += evsum + a;
```

Sure you want to do that? ;)

Answer (score 2):

This does not look correct:

```
evsum += evsum + a;
//    ^^ Maybe =
```

Answer (score 2):

`evsum += evsum + a;` there is a typo in this line it should be either `evsum = evsum + a;` or `evsum += a;`

Answer (score 2):

Change the statement evsum+=evsum+a to evsum=evsum+a

You are mistakenly adding evsum twice to your final result in that line.

610+198+198=1006